# Angular material table: How to always activate filtering even without filter set?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular material table with a custom filtering:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (u: Underlying, f: string) => 
    this.activeUnderlyings.indexOf(u.symbol) > 0
    && defaultFilter(u, f);
}

applyFilter(event: Event) {
  const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

No matter what filter word is set or if it's not set at all, the items should always be filtered by `this.activeUnderlyings.indexOf(u.symbol) > 0`. However, the filtering is obviously only triggered, when `this.dataSource.filter` is set.

Is there a way to manually activate filtering?